# App Works on Lollipop but Crash on Pre-Lollipop Simulator

Tags: android

My app runs properly on simulator for Android 5.0.0 (Genymotion), but it crashes on all other lower API. MultiDex support has been added to mainactivity.java and build.gradle but it did not fix it.

Kindly advice.

build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "gym.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // Enabling multidex support.
   multiDexEnabled true }

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7}
 buildTypes {
 release {minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' }
    debug {
        debuggable true}}
 productFlavors {}}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'}
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
protected ImageButton composeButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    composeButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mainComposeButton);}

@Override protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) { super.attachBaseContext(base); MultiDex.install(this); }
```

activity_main.XML

```
 <ImageButton
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/mainComposeButton"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
               android:minHeight="60dp"
               android:minWidth="60dp"
               android:layout_margin="8dp"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end|center"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_content_create"
```

LogCat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{gym.myapp/gym.myApp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
        at gym.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

Comment: The problem is in your main activity layout XML in an `ImageButton` element on row #27. There's likely some additional stacktrace that tells what the problem is more specifically ("caused by").

Comment: Thanks for helping. The first ImageButton is at row#27 in layout XML and it is causing the error. Please let me know what other stacktrace that could be useful to explain the error.

Comment: Post the layout XML (at least that ImageButton part), and see if there's any additional stacktrace below the InflateException.

Comment: I am seeing "invalid layout param..." at 

android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

While on <Imagebutton>, there's a highlight saying "[Accessibility] Missing ContentDescription attribute on image"

Comment: Add your activity codes please.And use pastebin or add it on the question not here as a comment.